# How to ignore special chars?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assume the following code:

```
var text = "John\nDoe";
console.log(text);
```

I end up with two lines...

```
John
Doe
```

The variable `text` is passed into my function as a call to a web service, but the special chars are interpreted as a carriage return which breaks my hashing algorithms.  They are not interpreted as standard chars and giving bad hash values..  How do I get node.js to interpret them as literals?

I have no control over the values passed in.  Simply typing a double backslash is not an option.

I do not wish to remove all line breaks.  I want the line breaks to be string literals.  I want the \n as as string literal, and not be removed.

Comment: Try to escape it?

Comment: @ChangAlex - The values are passed into my function.  I have tried to escape it using `/\\\n/g, '\\\n'`  but I end up at the same place.

Comment: What is "your function" like?

Comment: And you know `using /\\\n/g, '\\\n'` does nothing?

Comment: Maybe `\n` to `\\n`?

Comment: here is a JSFiddle I was trying.. - https://jsfiddle.net/wgns4b79/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9fsokh24/1/)

Comment: @ChangAlex - Yes, I think that is exactly what I am trying to get...  Thank you!  I thought I needed to escape both the backslash and the `n`.

Comment: If this still not working in "your function", you may show us the code of that.
Because we don't know what "your function" actually do with string.

Comment: This seems to be working.  Please add an answer and I will award points.  Thank you!

Comment: It'd been changed to duplicate, but that's ok.
I'm glad to help you.

Comment: "*the special chars are interpreted as a carriage return*" - the characters **are** carriage returns. I suggest you fix your hashing algorithm to deal with them and not break.

Comment: @Bergi, if considering ASCII, carriage return is character 13, the backslash (a legitimate character) is character 92, and the lowercase letter 'n' is character 110.  The concept of `\n` representing ASCII character 13 is a language dependent concept.  This data was sent via a web service call and character 13 was not sent, but instead a byte array including characters 92 and 110 were sent.  These characters are *not* carriage returns, but were interpreted that way because Javascript assumes they are.

Comment: @barrypicker JavaScript parses these two characters into a newline when evaluating string literals, when executing code. When a web server receives the two characters in a http body, it does not automatically interpret them differently, they're still raw data - a byte array as you say. This has nothing to do with JavaScript - I hope you're not interpreting the byte array as code?! No, something in your server code says to parse the byte array into a string, and that code needs fixing. Please post it. Also, the hashing code still needs fixing, as someone could also send a raw character 13.

Comment: @Bergi - thank you for your comments.  I do not have access to the source code submitting the web request.  The hashing is working as expected - if someone passed char(13) it should be invalid, and it is.  The characters char(92), and char(110) are passed in and need to be validated as a literal, not as char(13).  By escaping it (per Chang Alex) the program seems to be hashing correctly.  Thank you for your assistance..

Comment: @barrypicker "*The characters char(92), and char(110) are passed in and need to be validated as a literal*" - yes. If you need help with this, [edit] your question to show us the code that is supposed to do this. You shouldn't need to un-escape the string afterwards, you shouldn't parse it like a JS(ON?) string in the first place.